# Where can I store the refresh and access token in django

Tags: django, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, django-sessions

I'm using django and trying to integrate it with quickbooks online through python-quickbooks package and already did so and it works fine, but the problem is I don't want to store the tokens in the request session because I'm trying to access them outside the views, to be exact I'm trying to send an invoice each time an invoice(invoice model from django) object was made I want to send one to quickbooks and I'm doing this through django signals but I can't access the session from the signals so where is the best place to store them on the server side?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new Django model just for your integration and query it when you need to get tokens. Especially it can be useful if you plan to have multiple integrations, you can add relation from object (which is related to signal) to "integration object".